# How to interpret the algebraic meaning of this bizarre integration by parts result?

Tags: integration

Recently, I was revising some integration by parts techniques but I got bizarre results that I don't know how to interpret. Suppose I have a function $f(x)$ such that its reciprocal is always well defined at all x (e.g. $f(x)$ can be $e^{-x^2}$). Then consider the following indefinite integral

$$\int \frac{1}{f(x)}dx$$
Let $1=u'$, $\frac{1}{f(x)}=v$. Then

$$\int \frac{1}{f(x)}dx=\frac{x}{f(x)}-\int -\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}xdx=\frac{x}{f(x)}+\int \frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}xdx$$
Now for the second integral, let $\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}=u'$ and $x=v$. Then

$$\frac{x}{f(x)}+\int \frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}xdx=\frac{x}{f(x)}+\left(-\frac{x}{f(x)}\right)-\int -\frac{0}{f(x)}dx$$
Therefore
$$\int \frac{1}{f(x)}dx=\frac{x}{f(x)}+\int \frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}xdx=0-\int 0dx=C$$
where $C\in \mathbb{R}$

This phenomenon sometimes happen when the 2nd integration by parts somehow "undoes" the 1st one and for some reason unable to return the original integral that we start with. But what does it mean?

> What is actually happening in terms of sequences and limits whenever this bizarre result pop up. That is, what is the mechanism that give rise to this bizarre result and why it failed to simply give back the expression $\int \frac{1}{f(x)}dx$?

Comment: I've done this integration. Where did the zero come from? Can you check that calculation in the second last line? I think there should be a one insteed of a zero, because the derivative of $x$ is $1$.

Comment: how did you get that $0$ ???

Comment: O crap thanks, yes, that's a careless mistake. Umm should I kill this question now...?

Comment: Best to leave it here, so that some may stumble upon it and say "why didn't I think of that?"